# How Android handle Soft Keyboard Hide/Show in Dialog

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Does the host activity of the dialog got restarted when the system show / hide the Soft Keyboard because of the focus change in dialog?

My application is Fragment-Driven. I have a lot of fragments going around. One of my fragment trigger an action to open a dialog. Inside that dialog, there is input field and when I tap on that input field, all the states of the UI on the host fragment (actually all the fragments, so must be affecting on Main Activity) got reset. In my activity, I have already put this.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

So, by right, even though the soft keyboard is being shown on Activity, it should not got restarted.

I don't think I need put any code because it is purely on the logic of how Android controls on soft keyboard shows / hide.

Edit: My question is NOT how to hide soft keyboard. My question is how to handle the LifeCycle restart when the soft keyboard appears.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is, in my underlying activity, I am having ListView. Because of that, when the soft-keyboard appear, the system check on the view from the host activity and try to PAN those ListView.

Because of that, the getView ( .. ) of the Adapter of the ListView got called and the UI states insides the items in ListView got refreshed.

The activity or fragment does not got restarted when the soft-keyboard appear if you put

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in your Activity or Application.

For the time being, I solved this by putting

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

in my host activity. It will not resize / pan the UI of the Activity when the Soft Keyboard appear. But, it is ok for me. All of my UI insides Activity or Fragments are not requesting any input from User. All the inputs are requesting with separate Dialog UI.

The above code does NOT affect the resize / pan on the Dialog. But, if you wants to make sure, put this in your Dialog subclass.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

I am NOT sure this is desirable way or not. But, it suits my situation and because this is my question, I feel I have an obligation to answer it when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

please use this method to hide your soft keyboard .call this method from onactivity result.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity context) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputManager != null)
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow().getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    }
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, My question is NOT how to hide soft keyboard. My question is how to handle the LifeCycle restart when the soft keyboard appears. Thanks anyway. :)